# WGET and Google Save Browsing API v4 -

Tags: linux, bash, centos, cpanel, wget

I'm configuring  Mod_Security on my server. The problem that im strugling with  pulling Google Save Browsing Database into my server as SecGsbLookupDb.dat file. They recommend to use WGET, but i cannot find example command, im not fluent with wget command as well. Cpanel doesn't have  sample command in documentation, so im stucked. 
Here is the commands that im use:

```
wget ttps://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/threatMatches:find?key=mykey
wget ttps://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/list?key=mykey
```

Its showing me 400 errors, 404 errors, don't know what im doing wrong. Maybe my wget command is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

cPanel forum mentioned

> You will need to consult with Google if you have obtained an API key and there's no valid download location. The feature was deprecated in Mod_Security after Google began forcing the use of an API key to download the file.